# Basic example of extensions of residue fields.

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory

Can anyone think of a simple example of the following:
$B/A$ is an integral extension of DVRs with quotient fields $L$ and $K$ and residue fields $\bar{L}$ and $\bar{K}$, $L/K$ is finite dimensional and Galois, but $\bar{L}/ \bar{K}$ is not separable.

(The above situation is dealt with in the first chapter of Serre's *Corps locaux* and a concrete example would be very helpful. I imagine there's a very simple example, but I'm currently drawing a blank. Thanks!)

Comment: Consider a function field galois extension such that a prime is totally ramified, then complete with respect to that prime.

Comment: Consider $A= \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p][t]_{(1-\zeta_p)}$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_p][t^{1/p}]_{(1-\zeta_p)}.$ Then $L := K(B)$ is the splitting field of $X^p -t$ over $K := K(A),$ but  $\overline{L} = \mathbb{F}_p(t^{1/p})$ and $\overline{K} = \mathbb{F}_p(t).$

Comment: I think that does it. Thanks!